# Image overlay in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am currently working on an Augmented Reality application for Android devices and want to modify camera preview with information I gained in previous steps.

Now there seem to be 2 ways to do this:

1. I could modify the `data[]` array to directly apply my overlay on the actual preview frame.
2. I could make a second view which holds the information to be displayed and display it over the camera preview.

Which of these approaches is the better one, and for what reason? I cannot see any advantages of one over the other yet.